# JBoss 5.1.0 - Configure separate log files for more applications deployed in one instance of JBoss

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

I configured the jboss-log4j.xml as you can see at the example. The problem is that app1 and app2 log files have completely the same content which is merged from both of them. It looks like the filter does not work at all...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">


<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  Log4j Configuration                                                  -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->


<!-- $Id: jboss-log4j.xml 87678 2009-04-22 16:47:08Z bstansberry@jboss.com $ -->


<!--
   | For more configuration information and examples see the Jakarta Log4j
   | owebsite: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j
 -->


<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <!-- application deployed in app1.ear -->
    <appender name="app1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"></errorHandler>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/../../../log/app1.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>


      <filter class="org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLFilter">
         <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
         <param name="DeployURL" value="app1.ear"/>
      </filter>
   </appender>

   <!-- application deployed in app2.ear -->
   <appender name="app2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"></errorHandler>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/../../../log/app2.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>


      <filter class="org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLFilter">
         <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
         <param name="DeployURL" value="app2.ear"/>
      </filter>
   </appender>

    <!-- error log for both of them -->
   <appender name="apperr" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/../../../../log/app.err"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>


      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>


      <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->


      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>


         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>


   <!-- ================================= -->
   <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
   <!-- ================================= -->


   <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <!-- In AS 5.0.x the server log threshold was set by a system
           property. In 5.1 and later we are instead using the system
           property to set the priority on the root logger (see <root/> below)
      <param name="Threshold" value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      -->

      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>


      <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->


      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] (Thread) Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>


         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>


   <!-- A size based file rolling appender
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>


     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!-- ============================== -->
   <!-- Append messages to the console -->
   <!-- ============================== -->


   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>


      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>


   <!-- ====================== -->
   <!-- More Appender examples -->
   <!-- ====================== -->


   <!-- Buffer events and log them asynchronously
   <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
     <appender-ref ref="SMTP"/>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!-- EMail events to an administrator
   <appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
     <param name="To" value="admin@myhost.domain.com"/>
     <param name="From" value="nobody@myhost.domain.com"/>
     <param name="Subject" value="JBoss Sever Errors"/>
     <param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="10"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!-- Syslog events
   <appender name="SYSLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL7"/>
     <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="true"/>
     <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ABSOLUTE},%c{1}] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!-- Log events to JMS (requires a topic to be created)
   <appender name="JMS" class="org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
     <param name="TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName" value="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
     <param name="TopicBindingName" value="topic/MyErrorsTopic"/>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!-- Log events through SNMP
   <appender name="TRAP_LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.ext.SNMPTrapAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="ImplementationClassName" value="org.apache.log4j.ext.JoeSNMPTrapSender"/>
     <param name="ManagementHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
     <param name="ManagementHostTrapListenPort" value="162"/>
     <param name="EnterpriseOID" value="1.3.6.1.4.1.24.0"/>
     <param name="LocalIPAddress" value="127.0.0.1"/>
     <param name="LocalTrapSendPort" value="161"/>
     <param name="GenericTrapType" value="6"/>
     <param name="SpecificTrapType" value="12345678"/>
     <param name="CommunityString" value="public"/>
     <param name="ForwardStackTraceWithTrap" value="true"/>
     <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
     <param name="ApplicationTrapOID" value="1.3.6.1.4.1.24.12.10.22.64"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d,%p,[%t],[%c],%m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!--  Emit events as JMX notifications
   <appender name="JMX" class="org.jboss.monitor.services.JMXNotificationAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>

      <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
      <param name="ObjectName" value="jboss.system:service=Logging,type=JMXNotificationAppender"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
   -->


   <!-- Security AUDIT Appender
   <appender name="AUDIT" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/audit.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
   -->

   <!-- ================ -->
   <!-- Limit categories -->
   <!-- ================ -->


   <!-- Limit the org.apache category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.apache">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the jacorb category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="jacorb">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Set the logging level of the JSF implementation that uses
      | java.util.logging. The jdk logging levels can be controlled
      | through the org.jboss.logging.log4j.JDKLevel class that
      | in addition to the standard log4j levels it adds support for
      | SEVERE, WARNING, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST
   -->
   <category name="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf">
     <priority value="INFO" class="org.jboss.logging.log4j.JDKLevel"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jgroups category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jgroups">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.quartz category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.quartz">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the com.sun category to INFO as its FINE is verbose -->
   <category name="com.sun">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the sun category to INFO as its FINE is verbose -->
   <category name="sun">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the javax.xml.bind category to INFO as its FINE is verbose -->
   <category name="javax.xml.bind">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit JBoss categories
   <category name="org.jboss">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>
   -->


   <!-- Limit the JSR77 categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.management">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>


   <!-- Limit the verbose facelets compiler -->
   <category name="facelets.compiler">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose ajax4jsf cache initialization -->
   <category name="org.ajax4jsf.cache">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose embedded jopr categories -->
   <category name="org.rhq">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose seam categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.seam">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Show the evolution of the DataSource pool in the logs [inUse/Available/Max]
   <category name="org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool">
     <priority value="TRACE"/>
   </category>
   -->


   <!-- Category specifically for Security Audit Provider
   <category name="org.jboss.security.audit.providers.LogAuditProvider" additivity="false">
     <priority value="TRACE"/>
     <appender-ref ref="AUDIT"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!-- Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jboss.serial">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Decrease the priority threshold for the org.jboss.varia category
   <category name="org.jboss.varia">
     <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!-- Enable JBossWS message tracing
   <category name="org.jboss.ws.core.MessageTrace">
     <priority value="TRACE"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!--
      | An example of enabling the custom TRACE level priority that is used
      | by the JBoss internals to diagnose low level details. This example
      | turns on TRACE level msgs for the org.jboss.ejb.plugins package and its
      | subpackages. This will produce A LOT of logging output.
      |
      | Note: since jboss AS 4.2.x, the trace level is supported natively by
      | log4j, so although the custom org.jboss.logging.XLevel priority will
      | still work, there is no need to use it. The two examples that follow
      | will both enable trace logging.
   <category name="org.jboss.system">
     <priority value="TRACE" class="org.jboss.logging.XLevel"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.jboss.ejb.plugins">
     <priority value="TRACE"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!--
       | Logs these events to SNMP:
           - server starts/stops
           - cluster evolution (node death/startup)
           - When an EJB archive is deployed (and associated verified messages)
           - When an EAR archive is deployed

   <category name="org.jboss.system.server.Server">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.ha.framework.interfaces.HAPartition.lifecycle">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>


   <category name="org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer">
     <priority value="ERROR" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="TRAP_LOG"/>
   </category>
   -->


   <!-- Clustering logging -->
   <!-- Uncomment the following to redirect the org.jgroups and
      org.jboss.ha categories to a cluster.log file.


   <appender name="CLUSTER" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/cluster.log"/>
     <param name="Append" value="false"/>
     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>


     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
     </layout>
   </appender>
   <category name="org.jgroups">
     <priority value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="CLUSTER"/>
   </category>
   <category name="org.jboss.ha">
     <priority value="DEBUG" />
     <appender-ref ref="CLUSTER"/>
   </category>
   -->

   <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->


   <root>
      <!--
         Set the root logger priority via a system property. Note this is parsed by log4j,
         so the full JBoss system property format is not supported; e.g.
         setting a default via ${jboss.server.log.threshold:WARN} will not work.
       -->
      <priority value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>

      <appender-ref ref="apperr"/>
      <appender-ref ref="app1"/>
      <appender-ref ref="app2"/>
   </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a "DenyAllFilter" at the end of the filter chain to get the intended result.

So add the following after all TCL-filters:

```
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />
```